# Apache Camel - how to pass query parameter into velocity template

Tags: apache-camel, velocity, http-request-parameters

I've got camel (2.16.4) routes described in Spring DSL like this

```
...
<from uri="restlet:http://localhost:8081/service_url?restletMethod=get"/>
<to uri="velocity:{{templates.uri}}/stub-answer.vm{{velocity.opts}}"/>
...
```

Typical request is like `http://localhost:8081/service_url?param1=123&param2=hello`

I want to obtain the value of request's query parameter with name param2 from rest endpoint to velocity endpoint (file stub-answer.vm)

According to docs, Camel should pass every parameter from request in message headers, i.e. `${headers.param2}`. It works fine with path parameters (`/service_url/{param3}`) but doesn't work with query parameters.

I found out that all query parameters are passed as a string into CamelHttpQuery header. And I've managed to extract it inside .vm file with help of Velocity language, like this

```
#set($splittedParams = $headers.CamelHttpQuery.split("\/"))
#set($splittedParamsSize = $splittedParams.size())
#set($param2Index = $splittedParamsSize - 1)
#set($param2 = $splittedParams[$param2Index])
```

But it's a ducktape and I believe there is more straight-forvard way to get request parameter by name (maybe with some route config in xml).

TIA.

Comment: I'm currently thinking of writing custom Processor and packing it into jar, then into OSGI bundle and use it inside camel route this way `<bean ref="queryParamTransformer" method="process"/>` or `<process><ref id="queryParams"/></process>`...

Comment: My attempt with Processor :) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50414055